# Socket.IO-client.java disconnect and reconnect repeatedly

Tags: java, android, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I am using [socket.io-client.java](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) 1.2.1 on my node server for my android project and the android socket connects with the server fine but after some minutes it automatically disconnect and reconnect repeatedly. i can't figure out the problem, can someone help me?

i am using socket.io-client-0.1.1.jar, engine.io-client-0.2.1.jar and Java-WebSocket-1.3.0.jar libraries.

here is the java code

```
private void socketTest() throws URISyntaxException{

    socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.169.2:8082");
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

      @Override
      public void call(Object... args) {
        socket.emit("test", "awesome");

      }

    }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

      @Override
      public void call(Object... args) {}

    });
    socket.connect();

}
```

and here is the server side code

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
       console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('test',function(msg){
       console.log("This is "+msg);
    });
});
```

and here is the log screenshot

[image]

Comment: There is a workaround for this. refer to [This](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java/issues/123#issuecomment-96066333)

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this problem by adding an option with infinity timeout to socket.io

```
 IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
 OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
 options.callFactory = clientBuilder.build();
 socket = IO.socket(URL, options);
```

Comment: It worked for me but what would be the repercussions.. and why does this error exist

Answer (score 4):

I have fetching same issue on `socket.io-client:1.0.0` client library in my Android project but after the Downgrade the `socket.io` version its work fine.Used below client version might be helpful you.

```
 compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

Comment: Hello, facing the same issue..after downgrading i receive 'xhr polling error'

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I used Socket.IO incorrectly on server side (Flask) and HTTP long polling was used under the hood instead of websockets. Turns out, Flask webserver doesn't support websockets, so I had to use `eventlet` WSGI server:

`run.py`

```
from myapp import create_app, socketio
import eventlet

eventlet.monkey_patch()

config = 'config.py'
app = create_app(config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

`extensions.py`

```
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
...
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

jwt = JWTManager()
...
socketio = SocketIO(logger=True, async_mode='eventlet')
```

`__init__.py`

```
import eventlet
from eventlet import wsgi
from myapp.extensions import jwt, socketio

def create_app(config_filename):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_pyfile(f"../{config_filename}")
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)

    register_extensions(app)

    wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)

def register_extensions(app):
    socketio.init_app(app)
```

On client side:

```
class MessagesRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val prefs: SharedPreferences
) {
    private val options = IO.Options.builder()
            .setTransports(arrayOf(WebSocket.NAME))
            .setExtraHeaders(
                    mapOf("Authorization" to listOf(prefs.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN, "")),
                          "Content-type" to listOf("application/json")))
            .build()
    private val socket = IO.socket(getBaseUrlForCurrentDevice(), options)
}
```